# How to show popup on index page only Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to integrate MailChimp WordPress popup on index page only.
I have edited `footer.php` of the main theme but now the popup is showing on all the pages.

Is there any way that I can show a popup on a specific page?

For example, I only want to show subscription popup on http://WebSite.com/ page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with checking body for class home. If body have home class it is home page.

`if ($('body').hasClass('home')) { // show pop up }`

Comment: Thank you for comment, Solved this issue using plain JS `if(document.body.classList.contains('home') === true){
// Code here
}`